# npm error ELIFECYCLE on ctrl+c

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I've started a new socket.io project with heroku. The server runs fine locally on windows. I start it with npm start but when I shut it down with ctrl + c I get this error in the console:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! test1@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225786
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test1@1.0.0 start script 'node index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the test1 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs test1
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls test1
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have searched for a solution but the very little I have been able to find has given no solution. I've tried updating npm and node, running npm install again, clearing the npm cache and probably some other actions I can't recall.

Here is my index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const path = require('path');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = express()
  .use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));

const io = socketIO(server);

const pg = require('pg');
var connectionString = "postgres://jdirjtnfueksiw:823e80fbae9599f0d6797f82342d83bccf1caea764b8a1659356f3ee89r69f94@ec1-78-222-138-451.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/jf84jd75jgu26d5?ssl=true";

pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        console.log('Database connection test successful');
    }
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.emit('connected');

        console.log('New connection from ' + socket.request.connection.remoteAddress);

        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log('Player left');
        });
    });
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.4"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "6.x",
    "express": "4.13.4",
    "socket.io": "1.4.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Does not happen every time. I am not using `socket.io` but I am using `express`. I don't think its a big issue but it seems that there is some signal we (express?) are not handling correctly.

Comment: Let's see if a bounty can help get an answer to this

Answer (score 5):

In the `index.js` can you try putting the following code:

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    process.exit();
});
```

I think the issue is that Ctrl+C kills the application but there is still some process running in the background. This will ensure that it is terminated.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Trying it out.... will reward you with the bounty if it works!

Comment: Digging into it, but people are suggesting that just calling `process.exit()` actually does not gracefully shutdown Express...

Comment: There seems to be some Express docs on this: https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/healthcheck-graceful-shutdown.html